# requesting AWS Certificate Manager cert for root domain works, but not www subdomain

Tags: ssl-certificate, aws-certificate-manager

I have a hosted zone for my apex domain `yzpaul.com`. I requested a certificate through AWS Certificate Manager for `yzpaul.com` and `www.yzpaul.com`. The `yzpaul.com` was approved almost instantly. I confirmed both CNAME records showed in the hosted zone. 24 hours later `www.yzpaul.com` still says pending. What am I missing here? Do I need to setup a hosted zone for the `www.yzpaul.com` subdomain or something. If so, why is this required?

I checked the hosted zones for the domain and noticed the apex domain has `.` on the end of its values, but the www subdomain does not. Is this relevant?

[image]

I used the Route53 DNS test tool inside the hosted zone for `yzpaul.com`. I picked CNAME and entered `yzpaul.com` all good. Then I entered `www.yzpaul.com` and got:

[image]

Comment: As soon as I posted I got a "close" vote. If someone could explain why I would be happy to correct the issue.

Comment: Can you add the screenshots of the records to be added in the AWS Certificate manager console? Verifying those records would be helpful.